# Google Calendar and SMS reminder

Tags: google-calendar, sms

I have a Google Calendar synchronized with Sunbird. Is there any possibility to set the SMS notification when I add an event via Sunbird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On you google calender  go to settings -> calender settings - > calenders -> Notifications

and set up a default reminder for sms this should do as you want it to.

http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=37079

Comment: @Matt: It doesn't work. When I add an event using Sunbird I still have only popup notification.

Comment: Does Sunbird specifiy any reminders? if so then the default one is overwritten causing the sms to not be sent

Comment: In Sunburd the only type of reminders are popup reminders, You just set the 'before time' of a popup. I thought that maybe there is an application that can set some type of notification to all new events, but I cant find one...

Comment: @Tom by not setting the before time in sunbird will give you your sms notification, but ofc this means you loose the sunbird popup, however this maybe replaceable with a browser plugin for example [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ookhcbgokankfmjafalglpofmolfopek)

Comment: @Matt: It works! Sms notification is more important that popup for me so this is the answer!

Comment: @Tom glad it worked for you :)