# Google Calendar and SMS reminder (Canada)

Tags: google-calendar, sms

While [Google Calendar SMS notification seems to work for many locations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16159/24327), does it work for Canada?  Reference:  http://cantada.ca/

The option seems grayed out:

[image]

However, Google seems to indicate that it's possible:

> Canada
>
> ```
> Aliant
> Bell Mobility
> Fido
> Microcell Telecommunications Inc. (Fido)
> MTS Mobility
> NorthernTel
> Rogers
> SaskTel Mobility
> TBAY Mobility
> Telebec
> Telus Mobility
> Virgin Mobile
> ```

http://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37226?hl=en#C

Comment: see also http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/36357/

Comment: asked on http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/calendar/K8_Vwl1OQlI/F1i8TqB7ez8J

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your phone number associated with your *account*?

I used the mobile reminder feature in four different European countries, I'd be surprised if it wouldn't work for Canada.

Your screenshot is from the settings for one specific calendar, you need to go to your general calendar settings to associated the phone number:

-> google.com/calendar

-> Options button (right side) -> Preferences

There should be four tabs (General, Calendar, Mobile, Labs)

-> Mobile

enter the number, verify and then go again to the preferences menu for this specific calendar

-> "Calendar" tab

-> TUFIR HAWAT (or any other calendar name)

-> Reminders

the option should now be available